# Comment text truncated in timeline

Tags: bug, comment, formatting, timeline

The comment text in the timeline view (mod only) seems to be truncated on the right when the text is long enough to wrap. It looks as if the line width is miscalculated.

[image: https://math.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/timeline/465751]

The source comments that run off are [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465718/whats-4-times-more-likely-than-80/465751#comment1004343_465751) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465718/whats-4-times-more-likely-than-80/465751#comment1004354_465751).

Comment: Timeline view is mod only? I'm not and I don't [see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yWMXs.jpg) a problem there...

Comment: @draks: thank you for confirming that the truncation is not seen for non-mods. I've checked with another mod, and they saw what I show.

Comment: I think that it would be useful to add a link to the [timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/465718/timeline) of the question in question to this post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: the mod-only timeline view has a different link as the normal user timeline view. If a mod looks at the normal user timeline view (such as the link you posted), a mod also see normal behaviour (i.e. no breakage).

Comment: Thanks for clarification @WillieWong. I did not know there are two different timelines, one visible only for mods. I thought that this is what robjohn sees at the usual timeline (and that it is displayed differently for mods).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I only found out, quite by accident, during our conversation in chat a week or so ago. I'm not surprised that it is not better known, since I don't recall seeing any documentation to that effect.